# Custom this when calling functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, this

Here's what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/nxCFn/

```
var il = new ImageLoader();

function ImageLoader() {
    this.n = 2;

    this.load = function() {
        //obviously, the this = the image and not the original instance of ImageLoader :(
        this.n++;
        console.log(this.n);
    }

    this.imgnam = "http://www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm.gif";

    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.src = this.imgnam;
    this.img.onload = this.load;
}​
```

Because the image is calling `.load()`  `this` from `load` points to the image. I want to make `this` from load point to the `ImageLoader` instance it "belongs" to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var that = this;
this.img.onload = function () { that.load();}
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy the `this` reference to a local variable, and make the event handler an anonymous function so that the local variable is caught in the closure for the function:

```
var that = this;

this.img.onload = function() { that.load() };
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Function.prototype.bind`

```
this.img.onload = this.load.bind(this);
```

Or you can use it right here since you make a new function for each instance.

```
this.load = function() {
    this.n++;
    console.log(this.n);
}.bind(this);


this.img.onload = this.load;
```

To support old browsers, you can make your own binder function instead.

```
function _binder(func, ctx /*, arg1, argn */) {
    var _slice = Array.prototype.slice,
        bound_args = _slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return function() {
        return func.apply(ctx, bound_args.concat(_slice.call(arguments)));
    }
}
```

Then do this.

```
this.img.onload = _binder(this.load, this);
```

Comment: Note: The `bind` method is only supported in recent browsers (e.g. IE 9+). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @Guffa: Noted. Already added a solution for legacy browsers.